# Stargate SG-1 S3E3 Fair Game: Why is the speaker's lectern so close to the Stargate?

Tags: stargate, stargate-sg1

In the episode where SG-1 is trapped on a prisoner's planet we learn from Daniel Jackson that the initial blue burst out of the Stargate is deadly and not a way to escape.

So why is the speaker's lectern where Hammond stays in this shot so close to the Stargate?

What if the Stargate activates from outside?

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If there is an unscheduled off-world activation, there is time to close the iris, which prevents anything (including the destructive *Kawhoosh*) from coming through.  If the gate were activated during the event, the iris would be closed immediately, and the gate room would also be evacuated.

Comment: As can be seen on numerous occasions, but for example, in SG1: Lost World, Part II

Comment: The technical term is Kawoosh

Comment: I could have sworn there was one episode where they were trying to dial out in order to prevent someone else from dialing in, and the kawoosh happened suddenly without warning.